# Multi-line text and symbols in Braces

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm hoping someone can help me tex something like the following in a clean manner:

[image]

Namely, two "collections" contained within braces, both collections having two lines, and containing both text and symbols.  I haven't been able to find anything along these line on this site, possibly only because it is unclear what to search for.

(I apologize if it is bad manners to include a picture, this is my first time using TexStackExchange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like one of these solutions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, bigstrut}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\set}{\{}{\}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}

\begin{document}
\[ \set*{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}\bigstrut[t]Principal\\$ \GL_N(\mathbf{R}) $-bundles\end{tabular}} =\set*{\bigstrut[t]\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}Real Vector Bundles\\of rank $N$ \end{tabular}} \]%
\bigskip

\[ \begin{Bmatrix*}[l]
 \bigstrut[t]\text{Principal}\\ \GL_N(\mathbf{R})\text{-bundles}
\end{Bmatrix*} = \begin{Bmatrix*}\bigstrut[t]\text{Real Vector Bundles}\\ \text{of rank }N \end{Bmatrix*}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks excellent, thanks!  In general, is there a way to center everything in one of these braces?  For example, the lefthand sides look slightly asymmetric.

Comment: @StephenPietromonaco: Yes, there's a way: add a `\bigstrut[t]` to the first line. It will add to this line height a length of `\bigstrutjot` (default 2pt). Please take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Done here with `\stackanchor`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
 \renewcommand\stacktype{L}
 \strutlongstacks{T}
 \left\{
   \stackanchor{Principal}{$GL_N(\mathbb{R})$-bundles}
 \right\} \longleftrightarrow \left\{
   \stackanchor{Real Vector Bundles}{of rank $N$}
 \right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]